# Determine the safest speed (i.e. without skidding)

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

Determine  the  safest  speed  (i.e.   without  skidding)  with  which  a  car can go around a circular track of radius 100 m which has a coefficient of friction $\mu= 0.23$ between the track and the car tyres.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to approach this question, please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a formula for the centripetal acceleration in uniform circular motion.  It involves the speed and the radius.  The mass of the car divides out.  Look up the formula and plug in.